# Complex Queries with NHibernate Criteria

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

I am having a problem using NHibernate criteria for the following task.

I have an object TNA with the following properties, along with others.

Id (int)
OrgUnit (an object with a Name string property)
Employee (an object with properties listed below)
A list of TrainingRecords (Each of which contains a Course object, a RequiredBy date property and a Status string property)
A TNATemplate object (which contains a Qualification string property)
A customer object

The Employee object contains the following properties, amongst others:

Forename (string)
Surname (string)
Occupation (dictionary object)
Shift (dictionary)

A dictionary object contains an id (int) and a description (string)

The user can create their own filters in our system, and these filters are implemented using criteria.

I am required to query the TNA objects to produce a fairly complex report, but the structure of our data is making this difficult.

Currently, we have multiple Select N+1 problems which I am finding difficulty in resolving.

Our current criteria (without any filtering) produces the following sql statement:

```
SELECT this_1_.OrgUnit_Id   as y0_,
       this_.Employee_id       as y1_,
       trainingre1_.Course_id  as y2_,
       trainingre1_.RequiredBy as y3_,
       this_.TNATemplate_id    as y4_,
       trainingre1_.TNAStatus  as y5_,
       this_1_.Customer_id  as y6_
FROM   tblTNA this_
       inner join tblModule this_1_
         on this_.Module_id = this_1_.Id
       left outer join tblTraining trainingre1_
         on this_.Module_id = trainingre1_.TNA_Id
       left outer join tblModule trainingre1_1_
         on trainingre1_.Module_id = trainingre1_1_.Id
WHERE  this_1_.Customer_id = 9 /* @p0 */
       and this_1_.IsArchive = 0 /* @p1 */
       and this_1_.IsActive = 1 /* @p2 */
       and not (trainingre1_.TNAStatus = 3 /* @p3 */)
```

This produces 35,000 rows. However, the report has to then get data for OrgUnit, Employee, Course and Customer.

The following is my code - can anyone see a way of making this more efficient?:

```
DetachedCriteria dc = this.BuildPermissions(moduleUser, typeof(TNA));
ICriteria criteria = dc.GetExecutableCriteria(this.Session);

criteria.SetReadOnly(true);
criteria.SetFlushMode(FlushMode.Never);

criteria.SetFetchMode("OrgUnit", FetchMode.Join);
criteria.SetFetchMode("Employee", FetchMode.Join);
criteria.SetFetchMode("TrainingRecords", FetchMode.Join);
criteria.SetFetchMode("TrainingRecords.Course", FetchMode.Join);
criteria.SetFetchMode("TNATemplate", FetchMode.Join);

criteria.CreateAlias("TrainingRecords", "TrainingRecords", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq("TrainingRecords.TNAStatus", TNAStatus.Optional)));

ProjectionList projectionList =
    Projections.ProjectionList()    
        .Add(Projections.Property("OrgUnit"), "OrgUnit")
        .Add(Projections.Property("Employee"), "Employee")
        .Add(Projections.Property("TrainingRecords.Course"), "Course")
        .Add(Projections.Property("TrainingRecords.RequiredBy"), "RequiredBy")
        .Add(Projections.Property("TNATemplate"), "TNATemplate")
        .Add(Projections.Property("TrainingRecords.TNAStatus"), "TNAStatus")
        .Add(Projections.Property("Customer"), "Customer");

ICriteria result = criteria.SetProjection(projectionList)
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<TrainingMatrix>());

return result.List<TrainingMatrix>();
```

Update:

I've added the following code, but the Course table is still being queried multiple times - the subquery never seems to be called:

```
    criteria.Future<TrainingMatrix>();

    var myCourseSubQuery = QueryOver.Of<Course>()
        .Where(a => a.Customer.Id == moduleUser.Customer.Id)
        .Select(x => x.Id, x => x.CourseName, x => x.CourseDate);

    IEnumerable<Course> courses = this.Session.QueryOver<Course>()
                                          .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(c => c.Id)
                                                .In(myCourseSubQuery)
                                          .Future();

    ICriteria result = criteria.SetProjection(projectionList)
                               .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<TrainingMatrix>());

    return result.List<TrainingMatrix>();
```

Comment: Try replacing `result.List<TrainingMatrix>()` to `result.Future<TrainingMatrix>().ToList()`. That will make it a future query and force it to run, along with your courses future query.

Comment: Also, why is your course subquery fetching three properties? You just need the `Id` property. I don't know what happens if a sub query selects multiple properties, but my prediction is that it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks very much Andrew - that works a treat.  I couldn't get it to work with just the id, and thought adding the three properties might have solved that.  Put it back to just the id, and added the code above, and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this using [NHibernate Futures](http://ayende.com/blog/3979/nhibernate-futures)

NHibernate will need to retrieve all of the OrgUnits, Employees, Courses, and Customers which feature in your main query.

So for each one of these items, create a future query.

(I'm using an uncompilable mixture of pseudo-code and QueryOver syntax, but it should get the point across)

```
 IEnumerable<Customer> customers = s.QueryOver<Customer>()
                                      .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(c => c.Id)
                                             .In(myCustomerSubQuery)
                                     .Future();
 IEnumerable<Course> couse = s.QueryOver<Course>()
                                       .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(c => c.Id)
                                             .In(myCourseSubQuery)
                                       .Future();
```

etc

Then make your final `TrainingMatrix` query a future query as well.

Because they are `Future` queries, they will all be run in a batch when you resolve any one of them. You will be effectively getting everything you need in one round trip to the database.

When nHibernate needs to instantiate, say, an employee instance, it will see that it has already retrieved the employee of that id and use that one.

Comment: Hi Andrew.  Thanks for your answer.  Can you provide a little more detail, as I am very unfamiliar with this.  How are myCustomerSubQuery and my CourseSubQuery defined?  Also to make the final query in my example a future, do I just use criteria.Future<SheTrainingMatrix>()?  Presumably, when I return result.List<TrainingMatrix>() this will all just work?

Comment: I've updated the original question with my attempt to use a future query.  However, this seems to have no effect.  I assume I'm doing something wrong, but I'm at a loss to see what that would be.